# Coloring table rows based on column values

Tags: python, conditional-statements, plotly

Say I am performing machine learning to predict colors, and I make a table with the true color and predicted color. I want to color an entire row red if the predicted color and true color do not match. For example:

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5]
true_color = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']
prediction = ['blue', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values= ['Number', 
                                                   'True Color', 'Prediction'
                                                   ]),
                 cells=dict(values=[number, true_color ,
                                   prediction]))])

fig.show()
```

How do I make the 2nd and 5th row red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the color of the row using fill_color:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go


number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
true_color = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue"]
prediction = ["blue", "green", "green", "yellow", "red"]


colors = ["red" if x != y else "white" for x, y in zip(true_color, prediction)]


fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Table(
            header=dict(values=["Number", "True Color", "Prediction"]),
            cells=dict(values=[number, true_color, prediction], fill_color=[colors]),
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

[image]